# VirtualBox VM won't start after removing a VDI

Tags: ubuntu, boot, virtualbox, vdi

My Ubuntu VM has 3 mounted VDIs. A system VDI and 2 storage VDIs.

After merging all files to one storage VDI the system won't boot anymore although the removed VDI was empty and not even used for system relevant files.

Answer (score 1):

Did you remove references to the other two VDI files in the VM's config? If any VDIs are missing and a VM is still pointed to them, the VM will complain.

Get rid of the references to them, point the VM to the new merged VDI, and you should be good to go again.